# How can I check if the text of a button contains an element of an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button

I'm pretty new to this so bear with me. What I'm trying to do is check if the button is currently displaying an element from an array; array Answers. What would be the best route to do so?

```
@IBAction func qButton1(_ sender: Any) {
    if (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle == (Answer in Answers){
        PickQuestion()

    }
    else{
        missedWords.append(quizLabel.text!)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the button's title to store data and compare it to a value.

Any time you write code who's logic depends on text displayed to the user you are paining yourself into a corner in terms of localization.

Using a numeric tag to index into an array of strings would be a much better idea.

Say you create an array of title strings.

Make each button's tag be 100 + the array index.

```
let startingTag = 100

@IBAction func qButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let index = sender.tag where startingTag >= 100 else {
      return
    }
    //fetch your string from the array of button title strings you set up.
    let stringToFind = strings[index]
    if answers.contains(where: {$0 == stringToFind}) {
      //Found the current' buttons' string in answers
    } else {
      //string not found
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you pass Any as sender and then cast to AnyObject. Anyway I would use filter in your case:
Suppose you have an array of Answer objects called answers and Answer has a property title

```
if let _ = answers.filter( { $0.title == (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle) }).first {
   PickQuestion()
} else{
    missedWords.append(quizLabel.text!)
}
```